# Amchart legend Margin between value and markers not working

Tags: angular, legend, amcharts

i have amcharts and i add legend to charts but show text value legend on marker
[image]

i set margin left and right to legend value but not work

```
    chart.legend.valueLabels.template.marginRight=10;
    chart.legend.valueLabels.template.marginLeft=10;
```

i will show legend like this
[image]

Comment: Make sure you have `chart.rtl = true;` set to enable support for arabic. See https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/rtl/

Comment: chart.rtl = true;  its work 
tank you Andrew Hill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have chart.rtl = true; set to enable support for Arabic.

See [amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/rtl](http://amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/rtl) for more details.